# Node.js + Express + Jade :: render( ... ) times out with Node v.0.8.12

Tags: node.js

I've been using Node.js + Express + Jade for a long time.
Since upgrading to node 0.8.12, the render( ... ) command just times out on my production server.

In this example, "1" is printed to the log, but "2" is not, and the page times out. Of course, I properly have a file called views/test.jade. And, again, this works fine on my test server with the same code...

```
console.log('1');
res.render('test');
console.log('2');
```

So I downgraded Node.js back to 0.6.18 (what I was using before) and the code works fine again. But I need the newer node version... the one major difference that I can think of is that 0.6.18 was installed on CentOS via YUM, but I had to make v0.8.12 myself because I could not find an appropriate package.

Here's what I've tried:

- Upgrading express (@3.0.0rc5) and jade (@0.26.3)
- Using a callback in the render() func (it is never called)
- Explicitly setting the views/ directory via app.set('views', absolute_path);
- Using an invalid template name intentionally in attempts to get an error. Still, nothing (no callback fired, no execution)
- Crying

Ideas?

Comment: Just a thought. Add callback to res.render() as a second parameter and check what is the error if it will be fired at all. Then maybe it is Express and Jade versions dependency, so you have to upgrade those modules as well after upgrading Node?

Comment: I've tried that, too. The callback is never called (note that, again, it works fine on my debug machine). Both machines are running the latest versions of Express and Jade, too.

Comment: What OS are you running Node on?

Comment: CentOS 5.4_x64_v5.6 ; note that 0.6.18 was installed via YUM but 0.8.12 I had to build myself (and add to the PATH var).

Comment: Well, there is no magic with res.render.  Go into the `node_modules` folder and find the `render` method in the `Express` folder. Set a breakpoint and step through the code to see where it is going wrong. You can also wrap the `render` call with a try...catch to see if something is throwing. I'm guessing something is.  Errors might also be getting swallowed if you have defined an error route, try commenting out your error route so things just crash.

Comment: Okay, I have no idea how I overlooked a simple try/catch. Now I'm getting an error in the catch "{ [Error: Cannot find module 'jade'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }". Wtf? I've tried installing jade explicitly from NPM, both with and without the -g flag. Not to mention, express installs jade automagically, too...

Comment: Are you installing modules locally with the app (which you should be) or globally? Do you see `jade` in your `node_modules/express` directory? You should also be able to get a stack trace from the error with 'e.stack' or 'console.trace()', that might be helpful.

Comment: Ah, hm, somehow it appears that it was getting removed. Once I installed (yet) again it worked. Thanks! I'll have to hunt down what was removing it. In the process of working on this, I ended up getting a big hint about the other problem I asked about that you were replying to (re: dropped requests to express). I'm going to go update that post.

Comment: I've added this as an answer below, please mark it as the answer so other people that hit this issue will be able to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `jade` is correctly installed.  If the render call is timing out, it most likely means that an error is being thrown that you are not handling.  You can check for errors being thrown like this:

```
try {
   res.render('test');
}
catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

Since `render` doesn't depend on much, I'd guess that the `jade` module isn't installed correctly.  Make sure that you see `jade` in your `node_modules\express` folder. If you don't, try re-installing:

```
npm install express
```

Comment: Bill, you've been a lifesaver so far. Other question updated too, btw ;)